# How Python can be used in the backend to read from and write to RabbitMQ?

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I have a project that uses Python for the backend, and RabbitMQ as middleware. Is there any method or example for me to learn and help me to understand the problem better that we can use Python to read from and also write to queue RabbitMQ?

Comment: The rabbitmq [homepage](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html) has python tutorials.

Comment: I did read the tutorial from the RabbitMQ homepage. However,  I don't understand what it means by saying write to and read from queue? Can you give me an example?

Comment: You mean a tutorial easier than one line of code and more well thought-out than by the makers of rabbitmq? No, I can't.

Comment: What is unclear about the words "read" and "write"? Would you prefer "consume" and "publish" instead? Do you understand what a queue is, in general?

Comment: I understand the queue is like you publish a message, which will go to the queue. After that, the queue will send the message to the correct consumer. I don't know the read and write is the same as you send a message such as "Hello World" to the queue and then the consumer will read the message from the queue such as display "Hello World" on the terminal. Is that write to and read from the queue means?